How do I trap the ArgumentOutOfRange Exception?
The following is a piece of C# code where the error occurs:
    try
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(0, indexes.Count).Select(i => dataRows[indexes[i]]);
    }
    catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex)
    {
        return null;
    }

However, the ArgumentOutOfRangeException still happens in the "return" line and not caught by the catch statement. Any ideas?

Can't duplicate the problem with the code posted.

Select is lazy, so the exception would be thrown where the sequence is enumerated, which I'm guessing is not in a try/catch.

To avoid the exception altogether: indexes.Where(i => i >= 0 && i < dataRows.Count).Select(i => dataRows[i]);

This will materialize the underlying IEnumerable and will throw on first exception
try
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, indexes.Count).Select(i => dataRows[indexes[i]]).ToList();
}
catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex)
{
    return null;
}

however, instead of using Enumerable.Range I think you could simplify you code to use
indexes.Select(i => dataRows[i]).ToList();

if you want to catch each individual exception you could do following:
return indexes.Select(i =>
{
    try
    {
        return dataRows[i]
    }
    catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}).ToList();

You can later filter it by is not null.
Options are many and it really depends what you want to achieve
